# jQuery popup for YouTube iframe not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I have the following code that is working great in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox the result is unacceptable as it makes the video take up the whole window. Any ideas and thoughts are appreciated.

```
$("a.link").click(function() {
    var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
    //console.log(a_href);
    $('#vidholder').prop('src', a_href);
    $('#vidholder').prop('height', 300);
    $('#vidholder').prop('width', 400);

    if ($("#vid-wrapper").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#vid-wrapper").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $("#vid-wrapper").hide();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Can you pst the whole html to see how the jquery links into the part of the JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to define `event`.

```
$("a.link").click(function(event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont' know if it's releated to the issue but do keep in mind that $.prop() is used for boolean attributes (for example the "checked" attribute). For value attributes like width and src you should use $.attr() so your code should look like:

```
$('#vidholder').attr('src', a_href);
$('#vidholder').attr('height', 300);
$('#vidholder').attr('width', 400);
```